# Is that possible to get list of Constraints of the particular Label in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

Is that possible to get list of Constraints of the particular Label in Neo4j?
For example, using call [someFunction] or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the neo4j docs on constraints https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/schema/constraints/#constraints-get-a-list-of-all-constraints-in-the-database you can make a call to `db.constraints()` and see if there is a constraint in the results for a particular label.

```
CALL db.constraints()
YIELD description AS desc
WHERE desc CONTAINS ':User'
RETURN desc
```

Comment: Is there a way to filter not with string matching? :(